# Using SCRUM in a company with deliver time is short

Tags: tfs, scrum

here in my company we're using SCRUM with TFS and sprints two weeks long, we have to maintain basically .net applications (web, desktop), android apps, and SAP programs.

So, we can't create a full sprint because there isn't enough work to do, but, at half sprint start to appear more Product Backlogs to take care of and everybody starts to apply pressure so their PBs be finished quickly (Basically emergencies).

We can't wait for the sprint to finish to attend this emergencies so we change priorities on the fly. So basically the sprints mean nothing to our team :/ and all the pretties charts lose meaning.

How we can deal with this, we are not living a project like day by day to have the knowledge of what tasks are going to appear at the next sprint.

Comment: Is this question about how to use Scrum in your environment, or how to use Scrum with TFS?  This question sounds like it's better suited for a different site on StackExchange

Comment: I think you should rename your question to do "how to deal with frequent interruptions and changing priorities".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Kanban would be a better approach if you can't commit to a two week timeboxed period but still would like to follow a formal process where "charts" make sense.

http://kanbanblog.com/explained/

Comment: I think it's because scrum is more project oriented that makes us forget about the sprints on the average day by day. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many tasks as needed to capture the work required to complete each item. For example, you have a task in Future Sprint, but you would complete it in Current Sprint, you can move this task to Sprint1:

[image]

More information of Sprint Plan, you can check:

- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scrum/define-sprints
- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scrum/sprint-planning